# How can I use a for loop properly in html?

Tags: php, html, charts

I have following issue. I am trying to create a pie chart using variables gained from a database. However, I struggle to have them displayed properly.

The way I attempted it with a for loop, they get displayed as a singular entity in the pie chart and don't get separated.

I see that it happens because there is no break line but I have no earthly idea how I can implement that.

I tried to create a bunch of lines like $whatever[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbmbw.png), whatevercount[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbmbw.png). But that doesn't work reliably because if $whatever[4] is the last variable that exists, then trying to have $whatever[5] displayed breaks the entire thing for me.

```
function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
                ['<?php for($i = 1; $i < $counter1; $i++) { 
                        echo $whatever[$i]; 
                        } ?>',     
                <?php for($j = 1; $j < $counter1; $j++) { 
                        echo $whatevercount[$j]; }?>],
                        ]);
```

The resulting pie chart is just 1 entity and doesn't get separated.

[image: Example of problem]

Comment: Where are you instantiating `$counter1`? In the code you provided it was never declared and would hold a NULL value.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific with what the other variables like $whatever and $whatevercount contain? And what exactly is $counter1?

Comment: I didn't include those because I felt like they are irrelevant and would only bulk up the post unnecessarily. Counter1 is just what it implies, it starts at 1 and increases in increments of 1. It would represent the upper limit of what's available.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over an array with foreach(), so you avoid trying to access to a position in that array that doesn't exist.

By the way the best way to go is probably creating a single array with the task name as key and the time spent as value :

```
$time_spent_on_task = array();
$time_spent_on_task['Task_one'] = 2;
$time_spent_on_task['Second_task'] = 4.5;
etc...
```

So you can loop over like this :

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

    echo '['.$key.','.$value.'],';

}
```

Which leads to something like this :

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    [{label: 'Task', type: 'string'},
    {label: 'Hours per Day', type: 'number'}],

    <?php
        foreach ($time_spent_on_task as $task => $time) {
            echo '['.$task.','.$time.'],';
        }
    ?>
]);
```

Clean and efficient :)